# Mahogany covered porch flooring- satin finish

Tags: porch

Mahogany covered porch flooring-We put in a mahogany floor on our covered porch which is open on the sides about 20 years ago and the color has held beautifully (no gray) but it always is very very dull looking. We are going to power wash it again, but what product can I get that would give it a little bit of a shine like satin finish rather than dull flat and last and not flake off Which I hear is a problem with some products. We have an upcoming wedding so I don’t care how much it costs I just want it to look good and hopefully last some period of time. Also what brand do you recommend and any tips on applying? Thank you.

Comment: Just about any varnish or finish can be had in a satin sheen. Do you have a more specific question? Product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: mop and glo will give it a lot of shine without much risk. for long-term, I prefer acrylics over polys as they don't chip; done right (ex cars), an acrylic finish literally bonds into one giant molecule. It's also waterproof unlike water-based poly, and won't yellow unlike oil-based poly.

Comment: Thank you dandavis. The porch is covered but outdoors (no walls just a roof). Is mop and glo an outdoor product? Thank you

Comment: Thank you Isherwood. I didn’t know that. Is there a website that does give honest reliable product information? Thank you